# How to make status change

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, javascript

I was attaching fronted view and SharePoint designer view in screen please refer image and help me how to implement the code[image: Please see the image and help me]

Comment: You need to use javascript(REST/JSOM) to update the list items on change of status selection.

Comment: Yes, then how can I implement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [multiselect](http://loudev.com/#demos) library for this requirement,here is sample demo script:

```
<select id='selectItems' multiple='multiple'></select>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/SiteAssets/MultiSelectjQLib/multi-select.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/SiteAssets/MultiSelectjQLib/jquery.multi-select.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(custom, "sp.js");
        function custom() {
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            //update list as your list
            var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("MultiSelectTest");
            //get the first item only, you may update the logic per you requirement
            var items = list.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());
            clientContext.load(items);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
                function () {
                    var listItemEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
                    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                        var _Title = oListItem.get_item('Title');
                        var _Status = oListItem.get_item('Status');
                        var _ID = oListItem.get_item('ID');
                        if (_Status) {
                            $('#selectItems').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", _ID).text(_Title));
                        } else {
                            $('#selectItems').append($("<option selected></option>").attr("value", _ID).text(_Title));
                        }
                    }
                    $('#selectItems').multiSelect({
                        afterSelect: function (values) {
                            alert("Select value: " + values);
                            var oListItem = list.getItemById(values);
                            oListItem.set_item('Status', false);
                            oListItem.update();

                            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
                               function () {
                                   alert('update complete');
                               },
                                function (sender, args) {
                                    console.log(args);
                                }
                            );
                        },
                        afterDeselect: function (values) {
                            alert("Deselect value: " + values);
                            var oListItem = list.getItemById(values);
                            oListItem.set_item('Status', true);
                            oListItem.update();

                            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
                               function () {
                                   alert('update complete');
                               },
                                function (sender, args) {
                                    console.log(args);
                                }
                            );
                        }
                    })
                },
                    function (sender, args) {
                        console.log(args);
                    })
        }
    </script>
```

Update the CSS accordingly.

[image]

Result.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @Lee_MSFT how can I add second box(that means inactive status select box)

Comment: it's working fine but after refresh the fronted page false fields are display in first select dropdown list,but SharePoint DB is not changed

Comment: If you don't got 'update complete' alert, try to debug the update logic(afterSelect/afterDeselect), as I tested the script in my local, it's working fine even reload page.